# Tensorflow error "feed a value for placeholder tensor" occurs on the second RBM in a deep belief net

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I first constructed an RBM and tested it on a set of data, it worked well. Then I wrote a DBN with stacked RBM and trained it with the same set of data. The program stopped with the following error when it tried to train the second RBM.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\DL_DG\analysis\debug\debug_01_ppi.py", line 44, in <module>
    ppi_dbn.fit(ppi_in)
  File "D:/Python/DL_DG/Model\dbn_test.py", line 95, in fit
    rbm.fit(input_data)
  File "D:/Python/DL_DG/Model\rbm_test.py", line 295, in fit
    self.partial_fit(batch_x, b, e)
  File "D:/Python/DL_DG/Model\rbm_test.py", line 188, in partial_fit
    feed_dict={self.x: batch_x})
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/x' with dtype float and shape [?,128]
     [[Node: input/x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,128], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'input/x', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 142, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 460, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "D:\Python\DL_DG\analysis\debug\debug_01_ppi.py", line 42, in <module>
    learning_rate_rbm=[0.001,0.01],rbm_gauss_visible=True)
  File "D:/Python/DL_DG/Model\dbn_test.py", line 52, in __init__
    sample_gauss_visible=self.sample_gauss_visible, sigma=self.sigma))
  File "D:/Python/DL_DG/Model\rbm_test.py", line 358, in __init__
    xavier_const,err_function,use_tqdm,tqdm)
  File "D:/Python/DL_DG/Model\rbm_test.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_visible],name='x')
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1548, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 2094, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\pil562\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/x' with dtype float and shape [?,128]
     [[Node: input/x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,128], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

The error occurs at the following function:

```
def partial_fit(self, batch_x, k, j):
        print(batch_x.dtype, batch_x.shape)
        summary, _ = self.sess.run([self.merged, self.update_weights + self.update_deltas],
                                feed_dict={self.x: batch_x})
        self.train_writer.add_summary(summary, k*self.batch_size+j)
```

I output the type and shape of batch_x. The shape is the same during the whole training process. The type is **float64** when training the first rbm, and **float32** when training the second rbm. That's where it stopped and throw out the error.
The DBN worked well when I didn't compute the summary and just used the following code:

```
self.sess.run(self.update_weights + self.update_deltas,feed_dict={self.x: batch_x})
```

It also worked well if I only train a single RBM (with or without the summary).
The batch_x used to train the second RBM is probabilities of the hidden layer in the first RBM.
Could somebody help me solve this problem? I'm not sure if the **float64** is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's hard for anyone to solve the problem only with the two pieces of code I give. lol. The full code is too long to post here.

I save the output of the first RBM and use it as input to train another RBM. It works well. Thus, I think the problem is not the type or shape of the feeded batch_x, but the structure of the DBN, or the way I collected summaries.

Hope my situation can help others with similar problems.